# Last.fm API: Events venues with empty city

Tags: api, last.fm

Hi – Please check out this event pulled with the `event.getInfo` method: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=event.getinfo&event=2054422&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026

Notice the venue info:

```
<venue>
    <id>8887551</id>
    <name>Berlin Arena</name>
    <location>
        <city/>
        <country>Germany</country>
        <street>Eichenstraße 4</street>
        <postalcode/>
        ...
    </location>
    ...
</venue>
```

So the city is empty.

However, if you go to the [venue page](http://www.last.fm/venue/8887551+Berlin+Arena) you'll see "Berlin" in the address. Click "Edit" and you'll see that, in fact, the city is empty.

So, somehow, last.fm knows the venue is in Berlin, but it just won't return that info via the API.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the Geo data provieded via the API? You can query lat and long via Google Maps for example to get the city if it's not provided via Last.fm

http://g.co/maps/akrj2 (geo coords entered in Gmaps)

Comment: Well, that's a good idea, but it will require calling yet another web service and add more request time and all that. But anyways, it seems I don't have many options. Thanks.

Comment: I think Last.fm does the same and saves locations in a local database. If you create a huge event database, you could also do this.

Comment: I might have to do that, yeah, or just not show cities because it seems like too much effort and the feature I'm coding is not worth it.  Thanks.

Comment: ..but it definitely seems to me like bad API practice from Last.fm if you ask me. They should always provide comprehensive data, and make it as similar as possible to what the users can see on the website.